# Http cookie not added to collection

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Maybe I am doing something wrong, but after adding cookies to `this.Response` cookie collection in MVC:

```
   HttpCookie cookieRefreshToken = new HttpCookie("RefreshToken");
   cookieRefreshToken.Value = string.Format("{0}", refreshToken);
   cookieRefreshToken.Expires = new DateTime(2017, 12, 01);
   response.Cookies.Add(cookieRefreshToken);
```

When I try to access the cookies in different action - there are no cookies :

```
var cookie = request.Cookies.Get("RefreshToken").Value;
```

where request is of type HttpRequestBase and response is of type HttpResponseBase

Am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: `"RefreshToken"` != `"Expiration"`

Comment: Sorry, I have multiple cookies, i just copied the wrong one. I edited the post

Comment: cookieRefreshToken.Value = string.Format("{0}", refreshToken); what is refreshToken?

Comment: Its string with token value. For example: "59d57da0274944eb96a90eb256431f24"

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
   HttpCookie cookieRefreshToken = new HttpCookie("RefreshToken");
   cookieRefreshToken.Value = string.Format("{0}", refreshToken);
   cookieRefreshToken.Expires = new DateTime(2017, 12, 01);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookieRefreshToken);

 var cookies= HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["RefreshToken"];
 string values = cookies.Value;
```

Comment: It's still empty

Comment: If its in the same action I can see the cookie. But if I try to access it in another action the collection is empty

Comment: Yes, I did that also HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookieRefreshToken)